# editing for Lab 14

Tags: methods, constructor

I know I've already asked about Lab 14, but I've edited my code a lot since then. I think its a lot better, but I think something is still wrong. Is it with the setters? I looked on another forum that says I'm making progress, but while they get back to me, I need someone to help edit my syntax. If what I'm doing wrong is my setters, I'll be fine but tell me that please.

I really really really really want to get this program working so that I can move on since I'm behind in class. Yes, this is Java.

Here's my code:

```
public class StreetAddress

{
    public String street;

    public String city;

    public String state;

    public String zip;



   public StreetAddress(String findStreet, String findCity,String findState,String findZIP) {
       street = findStreet;

       city = findCity;

       state = findState;

       zip = findZIP;
  }


  public String getStreet() {
      return street;
  }

  public void makeStreet(String street) {
      this.street = street;
  }



  public String getcity() {
      return city;
  }



  public void makeCity(String city) {
      this.city = city;
  }

  public String getState() {
     return state;
  }



  public void makeState(String state) {
      this.state = state;
 }

public String getZip() {

    return zip;


public void makeZip(String zip) {
      this.zip = zip;
}



}

}

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have three closing braces at the end! It should be only one and you forgot to write closing brace for your `getZip` Method. One more problem with your code is that you have defined your instance variables `public` which doesn't make any sense when you are implementing accessors for them. As a result, you'd better to make them private so you also follow the encapsulation topic of OOP. One other problem with your naming is your setters' naming convention. It is a common convention in Java programming that you name your getter as `get[InstanceVatiableName]` ie: `getStreet` and your setter like: `set[InstanceVariableName]` ie: `setStreet`.

I have corrected mentioned problems for your code in below:

```
public class StreetAddress
{
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;

    public StreetAddress(String findStreet, String findCity, String findState, String findZIP) {
        street = findStreet;
        city = findCity;
        state = findState;
        zip = findZIP;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getcity() {
        return city;
    } 

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
       return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

Comment: IF that last `}` is for closing the class definition, yes like that. I have corrected your code and clean it in top example

Comment: I think there might be a second part. There's also a set of test examples and another code pad, but I guess that's another question on this forum. Haha.

Comment: Good luck with that, I also updated the answer to point out more tips about your code. And please choose the answer to your question so people can get credit for it.

Comment: I already fixed it yesterday. Thanks though. Your solution is the one that worked.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped you, please mark it as answer to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in any of the 2 ways.

1. Using parameterized constructor

   ```
   class StreetAddress

   {
   public String street;
   public String city;
   public String state;
   public String zip;
   public StreetAddress(String findStreet, String findCity,String findState,String findZIP){
       street = findStreet;
       city = findCity;
       state = findState;
       zip = findZIP;
   }

   public String getStreet() {
    return street;
   }

   public String getcity() {
     return city;
   }
    public String getState(){
    return state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
     return zip;
     }

   }
   ```

   and pass values from main function during calling of `StreetAddress` object.
2. by using Default constructor,

   ```
   class StreetAddress

   {
   public String street;
   public String city;
   public String state;
   public String zip;


   public String getStreet() {
      return street;
   }

   public void makeStreet(String street){
       this.street = street;
   }

   public String getcity() {
    return city;
   }
   public void makeCity(String city){
     this.city = city;
   }
   public String getState(){
    return state;
   }

   public void makeState(String state){
     this.state = state;
   }
   public String getZip() {
     return zip;
   }


   }
   ```

and pass values directly by calling functions `makeZip(anyString);`